# Web service generated client - does it use Holder objects for return values?

Tags: java, wsdl, axis

For production used web service-client mechanism we are implementing new feature pretty much similar to already used. 
New method is using the same description like the previous features inside wsdl. 
The client side is generated inside Eclipse using Apache Axis (1.).

wsdl

```
<wsdl:operation name="Work">
    <soap:operation soapAction="WORK" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="llws:Header2" part="Header" use="literal"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="Work">
    <wsdl:input message="test:WorkRequestObject"/>
    <wsdl:output message="test:WorkResponseObject"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

What is confusing me is different syntax of generated method. First method is generated with signature:

```
public ResponseObject doSomething(RequestObject)
```

while second method is generated with signature like

```
public void doSomeOtheWork (RequestObject, javax.xml.rpc.holders.BigIntegerHolder, javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder)
```

Why is this done this way? Why both methods aren't generated using the same syntax? Could it be that first method is already present and generator is leaving it unchanged whilst second one is generated with the another version/lib are therefor I get another signature?